# Obtaining a USSD code and a response to it using the USSD menu, using the smpplib v2.2.3 library

Tags: python-3.x, smpp, ussd

The task is to create a USSD menu. Connecting to USSDC using the SMPP protocol. USSDC [description](https://vdocuments.mx/smpp-for-ussd-services-1113-forussdservices1132pdf-npi-mappings.html)

I can connect to USSDC, according to the client logs the USSD code itself reaches the application, but I can’t provide a response message to the subscriber - with the USSD menu tree itself being returned to him.
To do this, we needed to add a couple of optional parameters to the library.

"    'ussd_service_op': 0x501,
'ussd_id_session': 0x1501,
'ussd_imsi': 0x1502,
'vlr_num_ton':0x1503,
'vlr_num_npi':0x1504,
'vlr_num_addr':0x1505,
"

The first message from the subscriber to the application arrives in the DeliverSM package, while the response to the subscriber must be returned in the SubmitSM package

Python v3.12. smpplib v2.2.3

I tried different ways to respond to DeliverSM to send a message to the subscriber, but it didn’t work.